# How to open the parent directory from the results of `which`?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, directory

For example, `$ open $(which bash)` opens the executable file. What would be the syntax for`open $(which bash <parent_directory>)`?

In this case, it would be the equivalent of `$ open /bin`, but without knowing the parent directory, how would I extract the parent directory path from `which`? Is there a more appropriate command?

Specifically, I am using the Git Bash app on Win10. I want to open the file in the Windows Explorer to get the Windows syntax path to the file. As a use case, I am trying to set up the Atom text editor's [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) package to use Git Bash instead of PowerShell. The Platformio package settings require the Windows syntax path. Maybe there is a better command to invoke the windows path?

Reading `$ man which` didn't reveal any such options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the [UNIX philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy):

> 1. Make each program do one thing well. To do a new job, build afresh rather than complicate old programs by adding new "features".
> 2. Expect the output of every program to become the input to another, as yet unknown, program.

`which` doesn't need to have an option to get the directory; you just need a command which takes a path and returns the parent.

```
open "$(dirname "$(which bash)")"
```

Comment: very nice - thank you for the context on thinking with UNIX philosophy!